# enable mediawiki sandbox page editing without user login

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to enable editing on a sanbox page on a wiki based website i maintain. To be able to be editable with a onkeypress or a button but with all other pages requiring a log in. Aim is to attract new comers to the website to be able to see how the wiki editor page works without having them create an account, below is the link of the page i want editable without a user login. How do i go about this?

https://zlb.uni-due.de/wiki/index.php?title=Sandkasten

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up permissions.

This URL will guide you through them:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights

Also, you take a look on this pages:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Page_specific_user_rights_extensions
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageSecurity

Comment: Thanks i will try that.